# How to make pre-selection in ng-options

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I have a Business dropdown, that is being populated with a list of objects. All I want to do is when I load the page I have business pre-selected with the data coming from my service.

Let's go through details

**json array of objects** for the select option

```
[{"code":"MA","value":"Main"},{"code":"TL","value":"Toll Free"},{"code":"AP","value":"After Hour"},{"code":"FX","value":"Fax"},{"code":"DR","value":"Direct"},{"code":"WB","value":"Web"},{"code":"EM","value":"Email"}]
```

**code for select option**

```
<select id="selectOption" ng-model="company.business" ng-options="option as 
option.value for option in businessDropdownValues" class="form-control form- 
control-sm input-sm"> </select>
```

Please tell me how do I get the pre-selected option if the `company.business` is received as one of the objects received from the list provided above?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share `company.business` object?

Comment: @Satpal {"code":"MA","value":"Main"} suppose this is the company.business object

Comment: `$scope.company.business = businessDropdownValues[0]`

Comment: @JBNizet but this is fixed, everytime it will select the 0 index, but we may have changed everytime.

Comment: Use `trackBy` expression i.e.  `in businessDropdownValues track by option.code`

Comment: Well, if you want to pre-select the 4th option, obviously, use `$scope.company.business = businessDropdownValues[3]`. What's the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet the problem is: when the page is loaded it fetches an object just like e.g. company.business = {"code":"MA","value":"Main"}

Comment: @JBNizet so if we received company.business filled with any object, how do we pre-select when the page is loaded initially.

Comment: Well, that is wrong. The company.business must NOT be a new object, different from all the objects in the array of options. It must be one of the objects in the array of options. Having the same properties and the same values isn't suffifient. It must be the same object. I.e. compoany.business must be `===` to one of the options. So, find the object, in the array, that has the code "MA", and set company.business to this object.

Comment: This is all explained in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions: *By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. This is important to know when binding the select to a model that is an object or a collection.

One issue occurs if you want to preselect an option. For example, if you set the model to an object that is equal to an object in your collection, ngOptions won't be able to set the selection, because the objects are not identical. So by default, you should always reference the item in your collection for preselections*.

Comment: But it does something completely different from what you asked. Now company.business is not an object anymore. It's a string (the code of the object). Note: I know how everything works, because I've read the documentation.

Comment: @JBNizet My bad. I am sorry because may be I couldn't ask what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like this.

```
 <select id="selectOption" ng-model="company.business" ng-options="option.value for option in businessDropdownValues track by option.code" class="form-control form- 
control-sm input-sm"> </select>
```

Comment: NP, it's our job.

Comment: Great, that's a Nice job :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this :

```
<select id="selectOption" ng-model="company.business" ng-options=" 
option.value for option in businessDropdownValues track by option.id" class="form-control form- 
control-sm input-sm"> </select>
```

Comment: you can use from above any one which you like.